# How to do rest call in jqGrid column?

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, jqgrid, jersey

I am working on a project which is a single page application and technologies are : spring framework, jersey rest, angularjs 1.2,9, oracle 12c and typescript. As I am new, I am finding it difficult to call the rest via typescript and angularjs.

Below is a column model in jqGrid:

```
       {

                    label:'Course ID',
                    name: 'courseId',
                    width: 150,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype:'select',
                    editoptions:{
                      value:courseId
                    },
                    stype:'select',
                    searchoptions:{
                        sopt:['eq','ne'],
                      value:courseId



    }
  },
```

In the 'editoptions' sectino, I need to rest-call for getting available courseId. How can I do that.

Comment: You can use `dataUrl` of `editoptions` to make the "rest-call" and to use `buildSelect` to convert the results returned from the server to the string with `<select>` and all `<option>` elements. You can search for `buildSelect` and `dataUrl` and will find some examples of the corresponding implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.